# Question on getting data from AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, jquery, dwr

I have a pagination table which has controls like left arrow/right arrow and a text box to directly enter any page number. 
Below that there is a table with 5 cols and 5 rows

Now I want to update the column data each time the user does any action (e.g. left arrow pressed) without refreshing the page.
So I am obviously looking for an AJAX based solution (can be with a combination of jQuery or DWR, etc)

But my main question is this;
Since the table structure (HTML code) is already part of a JSP and I only need to replace the data in multiple places, do I have to make multiple AJAX requests OR it can be handled with just 1 AJAX request? If yes, please let me know how it can be done.

Comment: AJAX will enable you to get data from the server without requiring a page refresh. What you do/how you use that data is irrelevant - if you want to get all your row data at once, just do it.

Comment: My question is not directly related to AJAX itself..I am asking what the overall and best approach would be to fill all the dynamic data in the various places of the table.

Comment: Then rephrase your question, edit your title, and make it more specific.

Comment: Well..u might not have understood the question correctly...So why should I rephrase it ?

Comment: If your question is not about AJAX, why title it "Question on getting data from AJAX"? It's too broad.

Comment: I cannot help if you still do NOT understand the question...Anyways someone has actually understood and answered the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about split the table part to another jsp and include it to your main jsp? When user changing page then you make ajax request to retrieve data and set the view to your new jsp file. Then replace the table with new html data you get back from ajax.

But if your table need more feature like sort column or anything else then I recommend you to use existing grid in JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Try jquery  [Flexigrid](http://www.kenthouse.com/blog/2009/07/fun-with-flexigrids/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't try to re-invent the wheel, but use a ready-made grid plugin.
there are a lot (see the links [here](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2011/02/unleash-the-grid/)).
I've used [jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) with much success.